# I am using Filament PHP and Laravel 9. There is no problem in local server but shows multiple livewire detected in the production server

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

I tried different node js and npm version. Tried composer update/install, npm install/update, npm run dev/buildm and even tried uploading zip file of the project which is running fine in local server. I have no idea what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try to delete the filament folder inside resources/views/vendor directory.
It should fix the problem.